# empty Selection.ShapeRange testing

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Button_valign_Click()
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = Selection.ShapeRange
  If sh Is Empty Then
    MsgBox ("Select at least two objects to use this function")

  Else
     Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
  End If

End Sub
```

I have a problem with a testing empty selection of ShapeRange. Which function I should use to do it property? I checking [...] Is Empty and Selection.ShapeRange.Count.  Any thoughts or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Count**

```
Private Button_valign_Click()
    Dim sh As Object, Kount As Long
    Set sh = Selection.ShapeRange
    Kount = sh.Count
    MsgBox Kount
      If Kount < 2 Then
        MsgBox ("Select at least two objects to use this function")
      Else
         Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
      End If
End Sub
```